# Android R.drawable symbol not found... (using netbean)

Tags: java, android, netbeans, drawable

First question

Wondering what is the correct way to import files downloaded from http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=876 into netbean.

These files don't have netbean workspace formatting.

It is a folder that consist of 
bin
gen
res
src
.classpath
.project
AndroidManifest.xml
default.properties

I tried to import to netbean but fail.

Should I just create a fresh new project, then replacing it with all these files?

Second question

I have created a new project called AccelerometerTest and paste all the codes provided by 
android sdk tool at /android-11/AccelerometerPlay folder into this new netbean project.

Then Clean and Build.

But AccelerometerPlayActivity.java compilation fail with error below:

```
Cannot find symbol
Symbol: variable ball
location: class android.R.drawable

Cannot find symbol
Symbol: variable wood
location: class android.R.drawable
```

Wondering how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete related files in \out\target\common\obj\APPS and I test this ok which the problem is same as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild your project it shall work